# Dynamically updating a JTable from a vector<vector<string>>

Tags: java, swing, vector

I have a function called FetchInbox() which fetches the header information (Sender, subject, date sent) of an email and then adds it to a Vector of String Vectors.

What I want to be able to do is to refresh this table as new emails come in and update the table by first running FetchInbox() again, and then using this to repopulate the table.

I know this can be done using a TableModel, but I have yet to find a example which uses Vectors and not Object[][]. Any assistance with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DefaultTableModel has constructors and methods that take Vectors instead of Object[]s.

The old version of DefaultTableModel only used Vectors, the Object[] parameters are newer methods that were added around the time Generics came to Java.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: the issue I'm having is now after implementing it with the DefaultTableModel, the table doesn't reflect the change of the vector of vectors when i call fireTableDataChanged(). Is this a graphical thing or am I calling the wrong method?

Answer (score 3):

When you create a table without providing it a `model`, it will have `DefaultTableModel` as it's default model. This model has two function:

1. `setDataVector(Vector dataVector, Vector columnIdentifiers)`: Where `dataVector` is a `Vector`(which represents the data rows of table) of `Vector` and comlumnIdentifiers is `Vector` containing identifiers. It will show your table as you are providing the Vector.
2. `addRow(Vector dataRow)`: it will add a data row to your `dataVector` as defined above.

So it is really simple to get the model and invoke these function:

```
 DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
 model.setDataVector(dataVector, comlnIdentifiers);
```

In your context, `dataVector` has the type `vector<vector<string> >`. But depending on `Vector` is not really a good choice. It is much safer and effective if your directly work with `Object[]`. The `DefaultTableModel` has similar function with Object array too.

1. `setDataVector(Object[][] dataVector, Object[] columnIdentifiers)`
2. `addRow(Object[] rowData)`

Check out the Tutorial page: [How to Use Table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) to know many more things you can do with table and it's model.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, but @jzd's answer is probably what you want, with the caveat that, according to the documentation, the column `Vector`s might be truncated or padded if their length does not match the number of columns you want in your table.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.util.*;

class test{
  public static void main(String[] _) {

    // Test data.
    final Vector<Vector<String>> rows = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      Vector<String> row = new Vector<String>();
      for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        row.add(String.format("%s, %s", i, j));
      }
      rows.add(row);
    }

    // With AbstractTableModel, you only need to implement three methods.
    TableModel model = new AbstractTableModel() {
      public int getRowCount() {
        return rows.size();
      }
      public int getColumnCount() {
        return rows.elementAt(0).size();
      }
      public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        return rows.elementAt(row).elementAt(column);
      }
    };

    // Test the TableModel in a JTable.
    JFrame jf = new JFrame("test");
    jf.setSize(512, 384);
    jf.setContentPane(new JScrollPane(new JTable(model)));
    jf.show();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [GlazedLists](http://www.glazedlists.com/) - it'll save you a ton of time.
with it you can dynamically bind a JTable to a List of objects such that any change in the objects is reflected in the table and vice-versa.